# There is any limit on how many critical section i can create?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

i have a Class that can be accessed on multiple thread.

To make sure i don't have simultaneous access i will use a CCriticalSection

I was wondering if i can just create a CCriticalSectionfor any copy of the object (i think i can have about 100-1000 this object in the program) or it will be best to create a static member CCriticalSection and use this for all the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to XP/Server 2003 you could run out of kernel objects for `CRITICAL_SECTION`s (specifically the event used to arbitrate when there was contention on the `CRITICAL_SECTION`). For XP and beyond you're bounded as you are for many things, by your virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is a limit, but 1000 is perfectly fine.
But in your case I believe static member is better.

Creating extra objects is the last thing you should do from the performance prospective.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has no limit on the number of sections you can create other than available memory (due to internal debug linkages, its consumes more than `sizeof(CCriticalSection)` or `sizeof(CriticalSection)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your scope was only to "signal" why not use InterlockedExchange and Interlock... family functions?