# Large number of critical sections

Tags: multithreading, windows-xp, critical-section

Environment: C++,VS 2008, MFC, app for Windows XP.
I have to access & modify a tree structure in 2 threads. My idea is to protect each node with an CCriticalSection that would lock each and every time the node inner data (not child) gets accessed. 
I am expecting large number of nodes (2-300000).

Can the very large number of critical sections be a problem?

I heard that Windows has an issue with large numbers of open handles, 
that is why I am asking this.

Comment: I'm sure someone else asked this very question today - can't find it though...

Comment: Similar to this question: [There is any limit on how many critical section i can create?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735719/there-is-any-limit-on-how-many-critical-section-i-can-create). However, that question has not yet been 'answered'.

Comment: I have searched for an answer too before posting this. I also could not find the similar question for some reason...Probably because I did not search for "critical-section" but for "critical section". Don't know. Anyway, I've got a much better answer:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike mutexes, Critical sections are not kernel objects and only require an OS handle as soon as there is actual attempt by two threads to lock it. [read this Matt Pietrek article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) if you want to know how it works.

Comment: This is quite revealing. So instantiating many Critical Sections should be ok, but it's not ok for many Mutexes instead. Very good article too, thank you :).

Comment: Unfortunately my "reputation" is too low to be able to give you some points. Sorry.

Comment: But critical section uses event object in background and that is kernel object. OK, in many practical cases event may not be needed (if the wait time is very short, so simple checking of shared variable is enough), but we don't know enough about internal implementation of critical section to say when is this event allocated. Also the software should be robust and should be able to handle worst possible case (i.e. all critical sections allocated some event).

Comment: Your reference to Matt Pietrek's article is now a dead link.  Can you confirm if one of the following are the intended article?  https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_critical_sections_and_deadlocks_2003.htm  https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_critical_sections_and_deadlocks_1996.htm